# How to overwrite older existing ID's when merging into new table?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, merge, uniqueidentifier

I currently am cacheing data from an API by storing all data to a temporary table and merging into a non-temp table where ID/UPDATED_AT is unique.

ID/UPDATED_AT example:

```
MERGE 
INTO             vet_data_patients_stg 
USING            vet_data_patients_temp_stg 
ON vet_data_patients_stg.updated_at=vet_data_patients_temp_stg.updated_at 
AND              vet_data_patients_stg.id=vet_data_patients_temp_stg.id 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT 
       ( 
              id, 
              updated_at, 
              <<<my_other_fields>>> 
       ) 
       VALUES 
       ( 
              vet_data_patients_temp_stg.id, 
              vet_data_patients_temp_stg.updated_at, 
              <<<my_other_fields>>> 
       )
```

My issue is that this method will leave older ID's/UPDATED_AT's also in the table, but I only want the ID with the most recent UPDATED_AT, to remove the older UPDATED_AT's, and only have unique ID's in the table.

Can I accomplish this by modifying my merge statement?

My python way of auto-generating the string is:

```
    merge_string = f'MERGE INTO {str.upper(tablex)}_{str.upper(envx)}
     USING {str.upper(tablex)}_TEMP_{str.upper(envx)} 
ON '+' AND '.join(f'{str.upper(tablex)}_{str.upper(envx)}.{x}={str.upper(tablex)}_TEMP_{str.upper(envx)}.{x}' for x in keysx) + f' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ({field_columnsx}) 
VALUES ' +  '(' + ','.join(f'{str.upper(tablex)}_TEMP_{str.upper(envx)}.{x}' for x in fieldsx) + ')'
```

---

**EDIT** *- Examples to more clearly illustrate goal -*

So if my TABLE_STG has:

```
ID|UPDATED_AT|FIELD
0|2018-01-01|X
1|2020-01-01|A
2|2020-02-01|B
```

And my API gets the following in TABLE_TEMP_STG:

```
ID|UPDATED_AT|FIELD
1|2020-02-01|A
2|2020-02-01|B
```

I currently end up with:

```
ID|UPDATED_AT|FIELD
0|2018-01-01|X
1|2020-01-01|A
1|2020-02-01|A
2|2020-02-01|B
```

But I really want tp remove the older updated_at's and end up with:

```
ID|UPDATED_AT|FIELD
0|2018-01-01|X
1|2020-02-01|A
2|2020-02-01|B
```

Comment: Nope and it would have less sense. What you need is a one-time step where get rid of the duplicated (aka *deduplication* or *cleaning* or *tidying up*). When this is done you will set up a *unique constraint* to prevent further problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, now that you mention it, I am using Snowflake which doesn't enforce unique constraints, only for optimization. Do you know how you'd issue the cleanup statement of ID's with older Updated_At's?

Comment: If you use Snowflage, than please do not tag with `Oracle`. In Oracle you need to *delete all but the newest row* for each `ID`. You can find tons of examles of *deduplication* even on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We can do deletes in the MATCHED branch of a MERGE statement. Your code needs to look like this:

```
MERGE 
INTO             vet_data_patients_stg 
USING            vet_data_patients_temp_stg 
ON vet_data_patients_stg.updated_at=vet_data_patients_temp_stg.updated_at 
AND              vet_data_patients_stg.id=vet_data_patients_temp_stg.id 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT 
       ( 
              id, 
              updated_at, 
              <<<my_other_fields>>> 
       ) 
       VALUES 
       ( 
              vet_data_patients_temp_stg.id, 
              vet_data_patients_temp_stg.updated_at, 
              <<<my_other_fields>>> 
       )
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE 
  SET some_other_field = vet_data_patients_temp_stg.some_other_field
  DELETE WHERE 1 = 1
```

This will delete **all the rows** which are updated, that is all the updated rows.

Note that you need to include the UPDATE clause even though you want to delete all of them. The DELETE logic is applied only to records which are updated, but the syntax doesn't allow us to leave it out.

There is a proof of concept on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=578ab950641ff50c2478b64f92e0d84a).

Re-writing the python code to generate this statement is left as an exercise for the reader :)

---

The Seeker hasn't posted a representative test case providing sample sets of input data and a desired outcome derived from those samples. So it may be that this doesn't do what they are expecting.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm looking for, except I only want to delete the older records if there is a new one to insert, which might mean I need to somehow nest the WHEN MATCHED into the WHEN NOT MATCHED somehow. But, you are right, let me throw an example into the original post as an edit.

Comment: Even this is an advanced approach that I *appreciate*, the *business value* of this advice is questionable. The statement is: "The table can contain duplicates, but *not* for patients that were updated *after I fixed my code*".

Comment: @MarmiteBomber My loader looks back every two days. In 2018 a user may have an entry with a certain id that this week, with the same id, has a new updated_at. Both would currently make it into the cache because the id/updated_at combo is different. But it's ultimately the same id so I want to remove the older updated_at from the cache. To be clear on the issue, the statement above is not yet where I'm at, even with my most current code the example in the updated post will still occur.